# Split an array by picking random indexes python

Tags: python, arrays, split

I have two python np.arrays called data and labels. I want to randomly reduced their size. In order to do so, I am doing the following:

```
np.random.seed(0)
ind = np.random.randint(len(data), size=(50000,))
reduced_data = data[ind, :]
reduced_labels = labels[ind]
```

I randomly pick 50000 from both labels and data. How can I store the rest of the data, so have can i find the rest indexes from the initial arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "randomly" reduce size, I would be very much against the use of a seed...

Apart from that, use boolean masking:

```
mask = np.ones(len(data), dtype=bool)
mask[ind] = False
reduced_data = data[~mask] #completely similar to data[ind]
rest_data = data[mask]
```

If you want to reduce the data by a set amount, I can think of the following:

```
ind = np.arange(len(data))
np.random.shuffle(ind)
ind = ind[:50000] #Or whatever the size is of what you want to reduce
```

Comment: How can I determine the size of the mask?

Comment: By the way you specify `ind` it is already defined as 50000 in this case, right? That is not completely true, as ind contains repetitions ... if you want to reduce without repetitions..let me think for a bit..

Comment: You are; all I said is that you are making the result deterministic by doing so, and if you want to pseudo-randomly reduce, it is probably not the way to go ;)

Comment: As a matter in fact i have data from two classes and I want in the end to be sure that the reduced arrays have approximately the same amount of data from both classes.